# Is there a list of dependencies for Android settings?

Tags: android, settings

I'm looking for a list of dependencies for Android settings.

One example is with the "Data Enabled" setting. When the user has this off, but enables a dependant setting such as "Automatically use network to sync time", you are not informed. Also, to receive MMS you need Data Enabled on, but this is misunderstood.

Any more dependencies?

TIA